# Android Rotating the device and lifecycle

Tags: android

I have a problem , it's not actually a problem it just that I'm following a book and it says when you rotate the device " ctrl+f12 " it'll destroy the current activity and create a new one, I'm following up in the logcat to see what happens but nothing is happening , it doesn't destroy the activity to create a new one , but it actually rotate + works just fine.

I'm using a newer version of everything , for example I'm using android 4.4 where this book is using an older version does this effect it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android 4.4 emulator does not support rotation at this time, due to some bug. Rotation works properly in Android 4.3 and lower emulators.

For example, here is the Android 4.4 emulator, in "landscape" mode, where the Contacts app is not rotated as it should be:

[image: Android 4.4 "Landscape"]

Here is the same setup on a 4.3 emulator:

[image: Android 4.3 Landscape]

Comment: It's strange man , I'm new but still , I created a new project for trageting 4.2 and compiling in 4.2 " jelly bean " it has the same problems still ,I changed the emulator and also the same problem , but I'll change it again and hopefully it'll work.

Comment: Wait a second , it actually worked when I changed the emulator + installing haxm which is now much faster , thanks man ^^

Answer (score 1):

Probably an emulator bug, for version 4.4:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61671